# Orchard Dynamic Forms Miscues

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, orchardcms

I am following the instructions from the Orchard documentations to use a dynamic form.

http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Creating-Dynamic-Forms/

The trouble is that it is not treating it like a form widget and so I can not place a form on a page.  I am sure that I am missing something.  It is being created as a content type but I can't put the form into the site.  I am sure I am doing something wrong.

I am using version 1.10.0 of Orchard.

Thanks gang.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere on onethird of the page of the documentation you referred to, there is the following content:

**Create a Form Widget**

Select Widgets in the left menu of the admin and find the appropriate Add button for the AsideSecond zone and add a Form Widget.

So there should be a 'Form widget' on the widgets page, where you can build the form based on a Layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic Forms in two ways:

1. Simply drag & drop the Form element onto a layout. This means you can add forms to any content type that has the Layout Part, including Page and Form content types.
2. If you want to use the form across multiple pages, then a Form Widget makes sense, as mentioned by devcon.

The Form Element can be placed on any layout, regardless of the type of the content item. So it is not necessary to create a Form content item, it's only there for semantic reasons (e.g. if you want a Contact Form page, you can create a Form instead of a Page, but a Page would be equally valid) and for new users to ease the discovery of the Form element.