# Orchard Dynamic Forms - there is not Form Widget available to use

Tags: forms, dynamic, widget, orchardcms

Trying to create a Contact Form where users can email the site admins.
Using the latest 1.10.2.0 Orchard version and despite enabling the `Dynamic forms` module I cannot seem to be able to get the `Form widget` in the list. 
Following the documentation from here http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Creating-Dynamic-Forms/#create-a-form-widget

[image]

Orchard retired the Custom Forms in favor of Dynamic forms however after hours of fiddling I cannot get them to work. I didn't get through the length of looking into the source code yet but having a form is basic functionality and it should work out of the box!
Note: I am aware that stackoverflow has few answered questions this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780231/orchard-dynamic-forms-miscues) seems to be the nearest to my problem, however the best answer it revolves around the ***Create a form widget*** that I cannot get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be there

[image]

If not, check if dynamics form module is enabled. Or check your logs if any error. Custom Forms module should be disabled.

Comment: yep I know it should be there seems to be a well know problem https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6260#issuecomment-319523301

Comment: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6260#issuecomment-445953487